# How to set DataGridColumn autosize upper limit, and still be able resize to bigger?

Tags: wpf

I have a DataGrid for displaying some unfixed datatable.

May some text data may will very long.

Since datatable is not fixed, so I binding the datatable to ItemsSource to make DataGrid auto generating column(MVVM).

And I can modify column in `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event.

I'm tried `MaxWidth`, but it's limit width and cannot resize to bigger.

Set `Width` will make all column width to a fixed value.

I wants to let the column can auto fit the cell conetent width, but if cell content width too big, column width will limit to a fixed value.

But still can resize it to bigger.

---

Maybe I can remove all column MaxWidth after all row loaded.

But is there a more "**MAGIC**" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `Loaded` event for the `DataGrid` and check whether there is a column width an `ActualWidth` greater than some pre-define max width, e.g.:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const double MaxWidth = 200;
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (dataGrid != null && dataGrid.Columns != null && dataGrid.IsLoaded)
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (column.ActualWidth > MaxWidth)
                column.Width = MaxWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no other "MAGIC" solution that I am aware of.

Comment: datatable is binding to DataGrid, so when DataGrid loaded, column are not generated yet

Comment: @Flithor: Are you sure about that? Did you try? Are you setting the source property dynamically *after* the DataGrid has been loaded? Otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: yes I have not hard code any column, and itemssource was binding to a ViewModel property source(MVVM), it will dynamic changing in running